# How are iOS Push Notifications triggered by another device

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

How are iOS Push Notifications usually triggered by device A to send the Push Notification to device B?
Does it usually work via the following procedure?

1. A triggers over a NSURLRequest a .php file which is located on the
   server
2. .php file queries Database for the device token of B
3. Within the same .php file a connection to APNS is created and the Push Notification is send to B's device token

Thanks & regards

Comment: Yes, your procedure is right. Go ahead and implement that way. It's work :)

Comment: But Don't forget save every device token of user like as A and B.